# Show that the image is spanned by the columns of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

No idea how to attempt this, was in an old exam paper for my linear algebra class

Comment: Do you realise you need to prove an equality between sets? You can prove a double inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

If $y \in$ Im$(T_A)$ then there exists an $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^T$ so that \begin{equation} y=Ax=x_1A_{*1}+\cdots+x_nA_{*n}, \end{equation} that is, $y$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$.